# Integrating 'PayPal-iOS-SDK' in swift 2.2 project

Tags: ios, paypal, swift2, xcode7.3

I am working on on existing project which is built in Xcode 7.3 and swift 2.2. The application have a feature of product order with payment via paypall. When I doing this for integrating PayPal-iOS-SDK.

```
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
```

The latest sdk is not supporting the previous version of Xcode project. After googling I found: For Xcode 7.3, paypal-ios-sdk version 2.14.1 is compatible. 'PayPal-iOS-SDK' version 2.14.1 is not installing, and showing the error.

```
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK', '~> 2.14.1'
```

This shows the following error:

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `PayPal-iOS-SDK~> 2.14.1`

But the current specification for paypal-ios-sdk is 2.16.0
Now What should I do to work with the Xcode 7.3 versioned existing project???

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this syntax?

```
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK', '~> 2.14.1'
```

Comment: Yah, After trying this, the error not finding specification. I have corrected your issue on the question.

Comment: Not sure about this but try 2.14.7.
I just tried `pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK', '~> 2.14.1'` with a new Xcode project and it seem to install the 2.14.7 version... (using Xcode 7.3)

Comment: Try `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`. Sometimes, it's enough to resolve a lots of problems

Comment: I tried of of your suggestions... But now it works with 2.12.9 versiion...

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try would be to use a more forgiving [pod version specification](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#specifying-pod-versions), such as

```
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK', '~> 2.14'
```

or even

```
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK', '~> 2'
```

if it doesn't break your code -- and it shouldn't, since Cocoapods promotes the use of [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/), which has a very concise [summary](http://semver.org/#summary):

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> 3. PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

If the developer dropped ver 2.14.1, but there are other versions available, you may be satisfied with those more recent non-breaking versions, which the `~>` syntax will pull for you (see below).

---

From ["Specifying Pod Versions"](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#specifying-pod-versions):

> **In addition to the logic operators CocoaPods has an optimistic operator `~>`:**
>
> - `'~> 0.1.2'` Version 0.1.2 and the versions up to 0.2, not including 0.2 and higher
> - `'~> 0.1'` Version 0.1 and the versions up to 1.0, not including 1.0 and higher
> - `'~> 0'` Version 0 and higher, this is basically the same as not having it.